# Design for throwing /axis rotate sounds

Tags: rotate, doppler, air

Hey,

Am interested to hear techniques for rotating air sounds - eg - dagger or axe been thrown.
I know GRM tools doppler can do a fantastic job on this. (which I dont have unfortunately).

Ive been playing around with SoundToys tremolator, automating speed up, and a bit of real time pitch with elastique and some EQ using a wind sound - which sounds pretty good.

Any other interesting techniques people use?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have you experimented reversing sounds? 
Find or record a few dozen sounds with strong decays (metal gate slams, reverbant door slams, distant gun shots, explosions, pressure releases etc) - reverse them and try those for the approach/attack of the doppler.... For the decay of the doppler try lower frequency sounds..

Experiment by recording backwards performances for both the attack & decay (ie have the shape of the sound you want in mind, but perform it knowing you will be reversing it) eg try dragging a wood saw across carpet in various shapes/performances, or scraping a machete across another metal object with the dynamic shape of the reverse of what you want....

Metal sounds may work well for the dagger, as the right sound will inferr sharpness

Obviously a woosh stops on impact, so a strong doppler up to the point of impact with an immediate/hard cut can accentuate the impact - but I think your question is for an object in flight? Try slowing the video to half speed, so you have more time to shape sounds to the actual movement, then pitch or timestretch it back to normal speed sync...

Experiment with recording first rather than plugins - while recording your first idea you will think of many other ideas that might offer a more interesting solution than processing...

Comment: @tim prebble Interesting! Great Ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try VariFi mode of Elastic Time in ProTools + triangle tempo change.
Or any LFO modulation of pitch in any sampler.
Noise sources IMO would work much better than tonal.
And than add some pan & volume automation.

and global slow pitch change when object is passing camera

Answer (score 1):

I usually use some whooshes or swooshes or swishes from the archive. You can also do it yourself by swinging around stuff in front of your microphone. You can use sticks or ropes for instance. You can act the movement of the axe, with mulpiple whooshes, so you get an organic feeling to the Sound.

If you want to make the Sound by using doppler effects, you can also use Waves doppler plugin. I usually use it for slower sounds, like car passbys or the Sound of trees passing by when you're inside a car or a train. With trees i would feed the doppler with various kinds of Wind in trees. With cars i would feed it with traffic